# Excel - Conditional Formatting - Updates Based on Current Date

Tags: excel, vba

How would I go about applying conditional formatting to a range of cells (Excel 2007) based on the current date?

I have a six-week plan (each column represents a day in the week (Monday to Friday, excluduing weekends)) and I would like to shade each column in green as the day passes without any user interaction, so that when I look at it, it will accurately have 'marked off' each day.

This is what I hope to achieve: I view the plan on Monday 1st January.  I then don't access it until Thursday 4th January; once the plan is opened, I will see that the columns M-W have been shaded in green, whereas the rest of the plan for the remainder of the six weeks remains unshaded and this should continue for the remainder of the duration of the six-week plan.

Is this possible?

I would imagine that VBA would be used to check the system time and then apply the formatting according to what day it is.

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**

This is how my planner looks:

[image: Planner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. The following should put you on the right track.

First, you can record the last time the workbook was accessed by storing the current date/time in a cell at the time when the workbook closes. This can be done using the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event, which has to be put in the workbook module. Open the VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F11</kbd>), then open the `ThisWorkbook` module and paste this code in it.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = Now()
End Sub
```

Every time the workbook is closed, the date/time at closing time will be noted in cell B2 (change this as you see fit).

In cell B3, use the `=NOW()` Excel formula to show the current date time. Cells B2 and B3 now define the interval within which your columns should be highlighted.

[image]

Then how to format the columns... Say your columns have date headers as in the image above. Select your "calendar" range (C5:I12 in the example above) and click Conditional Formatting > New Rule... > Use a formula. The formula should be `=AND(C$5>$B$2,C$5<$B$3)` meaning that only the columns whose date in the header is after the workbook was closed last time, but before now (adjust as you see fit), will be formatted. Click <kbd>Format...</kbd> to select e.g. a green fill, or whatever. Then <kbd>OK</kbd>.

[image]

Of course you could refine this in many ways (e.g. rounding to the previous or next day at midnight) but at least you should be on the right track now.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderfully-detailed answer.  I have attempted everything that you have said, but the conditional formatting is not working for some reason; I have changed the cell range/s where necessary, etc, but it does not work.  The dates (B4-AD4) are entered in DD/MM/YYYY format.  I have added a screenshot if that helps.  Thank you.

Comment: Sounds to me like you just need to experiment a bit with conditional formatting to understand how it works. It does take a bit of getting used to. I always seem to screw it up on my first try, and it usually takes me a few iterations to get it right. If you have a specific issue with conditional formatting, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Use this conditional formatting formula:

=IF(DAYS360(DATE(B$2;B$3;B$4);TODAY())>1;1;0)

what is does is
if(the difference between this colums date and today is more then 1 day, be true, otherwise false)

use it in a sheet like
[image]